# How can I have the placeholder text in my input instead of the value (today's date) when the page first loads?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, datepicker, fullcalendar

I have an input, which gets the value from full calendar, so whenever I pick a date, the input value updates. The problem is, when the page first loads, I'm getting today's date instead of the placeholder of the input, which is "YYYY/MM/DD".

How can I show the placeholder as the initial value and only update the value when the user picks a date from the calendar?

Here's my code:

```
  const [showCalendar, setShowCalendar] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    showCalendar
      ? (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden")
      : (document.body.style.overflow = "visible");
    document.addEventListener("click", onclick, false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", onclick, false);
    };
  }, [showCalendar]);

  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
  const { value} = props;
  const { language } = i18n;

const formattedDate = format(value, "y.MM.dd") 


 debugger 
  return (
    <DatePickerWrapper ref={wrapperRef}>
      <InputContainer>
        <Label>Date picker</Label>
        <DatePickerInput
          value = { value ? formattedDate.toString() : 0}
          placeholder= {"YYYY/MM/DD"}
          iconId={"calendar"}
          onClick={() => setShowCalendar(true)}
          />
      </InputContainer>
```

When using the component:

```
const [date, setDate] = React.useState<Date>(null);

  return (
        <DatePicker
          value={date}
          onChange={setDate}/>
```

Comment: `value = { value ? formattedDate.toString() : new Date()}` this helps you ?

Comment: unfortunately not, I still get today's date

Comment: `const formattedDate = format(value ? value: new Date(), "y.MM.dd");`

Comment: you are getting today's date because your `prop.value` is `undefined` ?

Comment: I've edited the code (please see above). I think the problem might be there. But setting the value to null should work, in theory?